# How to import index.vue files without specifying the file name using vue 3 and vite?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vite, rollup

I started working recently on a Vue 3 application which runs with vite and I am trying to restructure the directories so that I can group components and related sub-components in folders.

I am currently using `/path/to/MyComponent/index.vue` to import the higher-hierarchy component, and I would like to write the import statement without specifying the file name, so that I could do something like this:

```js
import MyComponent from `@/path/to/MyComponent`
```

where the files structure looks like the following:

```
path
│   
└───to
    │   
    └───MyComponent
        │   index.vue
        │   SubComponent.vue
        │   ...
```

I tried to play with the `resolve.alias` property in the `vite.config.ts` file, but I wasn't successful. Anyone managed to achieve this?

This is one of the attempts:

```js
export default defineConfig({
...
resolve: {
    alias: [
        {
            find: "@",
            replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
        },
        {
            find: /(^(?!.*[.](ts|js|tsx|jsx|vue|)$))/,
            replacement: "$1/index.vue",
        },
    ],
},
...
```

Comment: You can also use that one: https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-vue-components Will be faster overall and is already done + optimized for you.

Comment: Thank you @kissu, it seems like a very good workaround. I can see that there is not yet typescript [support for imported components](https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-vue-components#typescript), but a PR is already made, and it should be available soon.
I did find a solution with vite alias, which I will share shortlu, but I have issues to make it work with the ts linter.

Comment: I'm not using TS so I cannot really help there, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

### Possible solution

You could use index files and named import/exports.

###### Create an index file for your component group:

```js
// src/components/card/index.js

export { default as Card } from './card.vue'
export { default as CardTitle } from './cardTitle.vue'
export { default as CardText } from './cardText.vue'
```

###### The vite config:

Replace "components" in the `find` value for the alias you would like to use and replace "components" in the `replace` value with the folder where your components live.

```js
// vite.config.js

resolve: {
  alias: [
    {
      find: /^components(?:(\/[\w\-/]+))?/,
      replace: 'src/components/$1'
    },
  ]
}
```

###### Import the components from the index:

```js
<!-- src/pages/myPage.vue -->

<script setup>
import { Card, CardTitle, CardText } from 'components/card'
</script>
```

###### Visualization of regex:

[image]

---

### Optional extra steps

If you want to import everything from just 'components', this is possible too.

###### Create an index file in components folder:

Assuming you already have index files in sub-folders for components. For example: src/components/card, src/components/button

```js
// src/components/index.js

export * from './card'
export * from './button'
```

That's it, you can now do this:

```js
<!-- src/pages/myPage.vue -->

<script setup>
import { Card, Button } from 'components'
</script>
```

Comment: I don't really see the point of reinventing the wheel since Nuxt + other `unplugin` packages are already doing that one but thanks for your approach!

Comment: It's what OP asked for, I delivered a **possible** solution. Maybe OP doesn't want to use a third party package or Nuxt to accomplish this, then this would be a good answer. Else, OP should have been more specific.

Answer (score 0):

After trying various things I found a solution in line with my original post involvin modifying the `vite.config.ts` file `resolve.alias` property.

In addition I had to modify the tsconfig.json file to make sure that typescript compiler is also able to resolve the path to the `index.vue` file.

This is how I achieved importing a `index.vue` component only referencing the parent folder name:

#### 1. Vite configuration

```
// vite.config.ts

export default defineConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: [
            {
                find: /@\/components\/((?!.*[.](ts|js|tsx|jsx|vue)$).*$)/,
                replacement: fileURLToPath(
                    new URL("./src/components/$1/index.vue", import.meta.url)
                ),
            },
            {
                find: "@",
                replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
            },
            // ...
```

The above configuration code will tell vite to check if the import statement contains with `@/components` and does NOT end with any of the following extensions: `ts|js|tsx|jsx|vue`. E.g. `@/components/MyComponent`.

When these criteria are met the `find` path will be replaced with the path to the `index.vue` file within the `src/components` folder. E.g. `@/components/MyComponent/index.vue`.

The only limitations of the above solution is that it targets a specific folder (in this case the `components` folder). However we can add more alias objects to match any other folder where we want to implement this import pattern.

#### 2. Typescript configuration

If using typescript ESLint will throws two errors: `Missing file extension` and `Unable to resolve path to module`. This because the typescript compiler is agnostic of the above vite configuration.

For this reason I also had to modify the `tsconfig.json` file as following:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/components/*": ["./src/components/*", "./src/components/*/index.vue"],
            "@/*": ["./src/*"]
        }
    }
```

The above code will leverage [Typescript module resolution path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) to map everything that matches `@/components/*` to `./src/components/*`, where `*` represents the path within the `./src/components`. This path is relative to where the `tsconfig.json` file reside (as defined by the `baseUrl` parameter).

If a component is not found, Typescript compiler will look inside `./src/components/*/index.vue`.